# Does it matter where Apollo local resolvers are?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

Let's say I fetch data with something like:

```
  mutation Signup ($input: SignupInput!) {
    signup (input: $input) {
      success
      message
      login @client
    }
  }
```

and on the server

```
  signup (input: SignupInput!): Response!
```

The docs say:

> When Apollo Client executes this query and tries to find a result for the [login] field, it runs through the following steps:
>
> Has a resolver function been set that is associated with the field name [login]? If yes, run and return the result from the resolver function.

([ref](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#local-data-query-flow))

Based on that, it shouldn't matter where the `login` resolver is attached. However, it does matter (it executes the resolver only if it's a property of `Response`...).

So what is the intended behavior, the behavior or the documentation?

Thanks, just trying to understand this

Comment: edited the title to be more descriptive

Comment: The same thing is repeated a few lines later:

`Here when the GET_LAUNCH_DETAILS query is executed, Apollo Client looks for a local resolver associated with the isInCart field. Since we've defined a local resolver for the isInCart field in the ApolloClient constructor, it finds a resolver it can use.`

I'm getting the feeling it's a bug, just want to make sure I'm not the dummy :)